# upload images into database

Tags: php, mysql

I made a simple form to upload images but I receive the error message

> Unknown column 'images/16-08-2014-1408177181.jpg' in 'field list'

I read that the problem from quotes but I tried many and received the same error.
That's the project:

image.php

```
<form action="saveimage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

<table style="border-collapse: collapse; font: 12px Tahoma;" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tbody><tr>
<td>
<input name="uploadedimage" type="file">
</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input name="Upload Now" type="submit" value="Upload Image">
</td>
</tr>


</tbody></table>

</form>
```

saveimage.php

```
<?php
include("config2.php");
?>

<?php

    function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
     {
       if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
       switch($imagetype)
       {
           case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
           case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
           case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
           case 'image/png': return '.png';
           default: return false;
       }
     }



if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {

    $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
    $target_path = "images/".$imagename;


if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {

    $query_upload=mysql_query("insert into images_store(images_path,submission_date) Values(`".$target_path."`,`".date("Y-m-d")."`)")or die(mysql_error());
                        }

}

?>;
```

config2.php

```
<?php
/**********MYSQL Settings****************/
$host="localhost";
$databasename="db";
$user="root";
$pass="123456";
/**********MYSQL Settings****************/


$conn=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);

if($conn)
{
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($databasename, $conn);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
}
else
{
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

display_messag.php

```
 <?php
include("config2.php");

$select_query = "SELECT 'images_path' FROM  'images_store' ORDER by 'images_id' DESC";
$sql = mysql_query($select_query) or die(mysql_error());    
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_BOTH)){

?>

<table style="border-collapse: collapse; font: 12px Tahoma;" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tbody><tr>
<td>

<img src="<?php echo $row["images_path"];="" ?="">" alt="" />">

</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Please post the error too and tell what's on the line on which you are getting error

Comment: Now would be a good time to modernise

Answer (score 0):

You should be putting quotes around the string values in the `VALUES` list, not backticks.

```
$query_upload=mysql_query("insert into images_store(images_path,submission_date)
                           values('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')")
                or die(mysql_error());
```

The `SELECT` query should be:

```
$select_query = "SELECT `images_path` FROM  `images_store` ORDER by `images_id` DESC";
```

If you're going to quote column or table names, you have to do it with backticks, not single quotes or double quotes -- those are used around strings.

Comment: thank you very much :) , it's working and the image uploaded to images folder but the image file damaged , i don't know why ?!

Comment: I don't see any obvious reason for the file to be corrupted.

Comment: the problem was from folder permission thank you :) , if u don't mind can u tell me what error here , while trying to display message : ` <?php
include("config2.php");

$select_query = "SELECT 'images_path' FROM  'images_store' ORDER by 'images_id' DESC";
$sql = mysql_query($select_query) or die(mysql_error()); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_BOTH)){

?>

<table style="border-collapse: collapse; font: 12px Tahoma;" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tbody><tr>
<td>

<img src="<?php echo $row["images_path"];="" ?="">" alt="" />">

</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>

<?php
}
?>
`

Comment: That's totally unreadable. Don't try to put long codes into comments, you have to put them in the question so you can format it properly.

Comment: It looks like you have the wrong types of quotes in your query. Use backticks around table and column names, not single quotes.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I think you need to learn basic MySQL syntax, especially the different types of quoting.

Comment: i think the problem from line 14 and i solved it , but if i have many photos in database the command show all photos i think what code should i use to show photo by id  ?!

Comment: Use `WHERE image_id = $image_id` in your query to select a specific image.

Comment: at the first i know that am annoying you but i am sorry for that , but i see you are friendly and helpful person , while add WHERE image_id in the query i got an error and for the variable $image_id i should make it variable for ? , and when i want to show the specific image in echo what should i use with image_path , and really thank you for you help :)

Comment: You said you wanted to show the photo for a specific ID. So put that ID in `$image_id`.

Comment: i do that and the image appear , but i have a question in echo command now it's "echo $row["images_path"]; " how it know that i need that specific image and if i have more images with different ids what command should i use to display different images with different ids in echo command ?!

Comment: If you're selecting multiple images, you should use a `while` loop to retrieve all of them. The query should be `SELECT images_id, images_path ...`, then you can use `echo $row['images_id'` to echo the ID that goes with each path.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave out the backticks in the `VALUES` part. Like so

```
"INSERT INTO `images_store` (`images_path`, `submission_date`) VALUES ('$target_path', '" . date("Y-m-d") . "')"
```

Backticks make your database interpret its content as field names.

Comment: You need quotes around the date, too.